# Dask Distributed Getting Futures after Client Closed

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

Is there anyway to prevent dask/distributed from cancelling queued & executing futures when the client is closed?

I want to use a jupyter notebook to kick off some very long running simulations with distributed, close the notebook, and sometime later, retrieve the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "publish" mechanism to keep references to some data around in the scheduler for later retrieval in another client. Two forms exist which do the same thing with different syntax:

```
>>> client.publish_dataset(mydata=f)
```

Here `f` is a future, list of futures or a dask collection (dataframe, etc).

In another session:

```
>>> client.list_datasets()
['mydata']
>>> client.get_dataset('mydata')
<same thing as f>
```

The alternative and maybe simpler syntax looks like

```
>>> client.datasets['mydata'] = f

>>> list(client.datasets)
['mydata']
>>> client.datasets['mydata']
<same thing as f>
```

To remove the references and allow the data to be cleared from the cluster (if no client needs them), use `client.unpublish_dataset('mydata')` or `del client.datasets['mydata']`.

Comment: Hi mdurant, thanks for the response. I did try this method, but found that even with a published dataset, if client.close is called, the future is still cancelled even if it has been published.

Comment: I was mistaken!  The original future (as returned by client.submit) is indeed cancelled, but it appears that client.get_dataset returns a *different* future which is still pending as the operation continues.  Thanks for suggesting this, it forced me to rethink my assumptions; I was likely going to abandon dask/distributed in favor of celery for my application.

Comment: Glad you don't need to abandon dask!