# Dask Distributed: access client futures from separate process

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I have launched many simulations with [Dask Distributed](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/):

```
from time import sleep
from distributed import Client, as_completed

def simulation(x):
    """ Proxy function for simulation """
    sleep(60 * 60 * 24)  # wait one day
    return hash(x)

def save(result):
    with open("result", "w") as f:
        print(result, file=f)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    client = Client("localhost:8786")
    futures = client.map(simulation, range(1000))

    for future in as_completed(future):
        result = future.result()
        save(result)
```

However, this code has a bug: `open("result", "w")` should be `open(str(result), "w")`. I'd like to correct that mistake, the re-process of the clients futures.

However, I do not know of a way to do that without stopping the Python process with a keyboard interrupt than re-submitting the jobs to the Dask cluster. I don't want to do that because these simulations have taken a couple days.

I want to access all the futures the client has and save all the existing results. How do I make that happen?

**Possibly relevant questions**

- "[Dask Distributed Getting Futures after Client Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49284512/dask-distributed-getting-futures-after-client-closed)" isn't relevant because the client connection is still open:

Answer (score 0):

[client.has_what](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/api.html#distributed.Client.has_what) is the method you're looking for:

```
from distributed import Client, Future

if __name__ == "__main__":
    client = Client("localhost:8786")
    futures = [Future(key) for keys in client.has_what().values() for key in keys]

    for future in as_completed(futures):
        ...
```